# Efficient algorithm to check if two arrays have the same values in Python. The values are guaranteed to be in the same order

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two images with white blobs of target objects on a black background. I need to exclude all blobs from set 2 if they overlap with a blob in set 1. My bruteforce approach is shown below, but it is inefficient.

Now, I can compute all contours of the initial mask and of the `mask * (1 -occupied)`. This yields two arrays_outer of arrays_inner of coordinates. If an array from array_inner1 has a match in the array_inner from array_outer2, then this contour should be included. Else - scipped. I would like to have a way to turn an array of coordinates (mutable type) into some sort of hash. Then do set intersect of hashes. Then use `cv2.drawContours` on arrays that survived intersect operation. Would this work? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

Progress so far. Bruteforce by

```
occupied_mask = fill_countours(contours0)  # numpy array of a mask of higher priority contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask_of_a_layer = np.zeros(occupied_mask.shape)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    tmp_mask = np.zeros(occupied_mask.shape)
    cv2.drawContours(tmp_mask, contours, i, color=1, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    if np.sum(tmp_mask) == if np.sum(tmp_mask * (1-occupied_mask)):
        mask_of_a_layer = (mask_of_a_layer + tmp_mask).clip(0,1)
        
occupied_mask = (occupied_mask + mask_of_a_layer).clip(0,1)
```

However, this is very inefficient: takes 10 seconds rather than ms.

[image]

On this picture we see a case of a partial overlap. The desired output should be

[image]

Comment: It should be very simple to do a flood fill of image 2 using image 1 as seeds. I don't know what functionality OpenCV has off the top of my head, but using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-BinaryPropagation-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-sint--dip-uint--dip-String-CL) you'd do `cleaned_img2 = img2 - dip.BinaryPropagation(img1, img2)`

Comment: connected components labeling. then some set operations, then gather the labels.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757888/does-opencv-python-guarantee-that-a-contour-remains-the-same-even-if-other-parts

Comment: The advice from the comment only works in case of a complete overlap.

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Both my suggestion and Christoph’s would work correctly for your problem.

Comment: sadly that nice composite with the colorful boxes isn't pure red and green. this is making it a little bit harder to show you a solution than it _needs_ to be. -- my suggestion literally just needs CC labeling, `&`, mask indexing, and `np.unique`. takes single-digit milliseconds on my decade-old midrange desktop. and I'm sure that could be sped up with some numba because numpy is often not specializing as much as it could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did measure timing. Geting contours costs 10 ms. My algo costs 10 s. Hence, I solved the probliem by reusing getContours. Caviat. It seems that cv2 doesnot guarantee that the contour always starts from the same point.Although it looks like it does (if it doesn't, you have to walk to find a matching point in an array).

Solution looks like this

```
from os import path
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
from acne_data_model import AcneDataModel as aDM
import pickle
from time import time

dts = ['nc', 'pap', 'pust', 'wd', 'bd']
with open('masks.pickle', 'rb') as fi:
    adm = pickle.load(fi)

last = len(dts)
masks = np.zeros((adm.masks['bd'].shape[0], adm.masks['bd'].shape[1], len(dts)+1)).astype(np.uint8)
masks[:, :, last] = 1  # is unoccupied. Should be masks[:, :, last] = gm
t1 = time()
for dt_index, dt in enumerate(dts):
    contours_init, hierarchy_init = cv2.findContours(adm.masks[dt] * 255, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours_new, hierarchy_new = cv2.findContours(adm.masks[dt] * 255 * masks[:,:,last], cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    init_set = set()
    init_dict = {}
    new_set = set()
    new_dict = {}
    contour2index = {}

    for i, contour in enumerate(contours_init):
        k = str(contour)
        contour2index[k] = i
        init_set.add(k)
        init_dict[k] = contour

    for contour in contours_new:
        k = str(contour)
        new_set.add(k)
        new_dict[k] = contour

    survivors = init_set.intersection(new_set)

    indexes = []
    mask = np.zeros((adm.masks['bd'].shape[0], adm.masks['bd'].shape[1])).astype(np.uint8)
    for survivor in survivors:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours_init, contour2index[survivor], color=1, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    masks[:, :, dt_index] = mask
    masks[:,:,last] = masks[:,:,last] * (1-masks[:,:, dt_index])

print(f'done in {time()-t1} s')
for i in range(masks.shape[2]-1):
    cv2.imwrite(path.join('scratch', f'{dts[i]}.png'), masks[:,:,i] * 255)
```

> what is  ['nc', 'pap', 'pust', 'wd', 'bd'] and adm?
> Well, those are the sources of masks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using

- connected components labeling
- boolean operations
- some mask indexing (gathering)

```
# Ferst, I vill ingeszt ze picture und dizsect its planes.

im = cv.imread("jTIAV.png")

plane1 = im[:,:,2] # red
plane2 = im[:,:,1] # green

plane1 = (plane1 >= 128)
plane2 = (plane2 >= 128)
```

[image]

[image]

```
# Nexzt, I vill label ze components.

(nlabels, labels) = cv.connectedComponents(plane1.astype(np.uint8))
```

```
# Now I vill find ze overlap und extracz ze labels in zis overlap.

overlap = plane1 & plane2
to_erase = np.unique(labels[overlap])
```

```
# Finallee, I vill erase zose components zat overlapped.

erased = plane1.copy()
for label in to_erase:
    erased[labels == label] = 0
```

[image: output]

```
# Now zat I see ze result of zis removal,
# I am inclined to use zis effect for nefarious purposes!
```

This runs in a handful of milliseconds on my decade-old mid-range desktop computer.

Comment: Sadly, it is very slow when you compare sets of thousands blobs.

Comment: @sixtytrees I can imagine that `erased[labels == label] = 0` is slow. You can replace this loop with a lookup table: `map = np.arange(nlabels+1); map[to_erase]=0; erased=map[labels]`. But this solution is much simpler and straight-forward than what you did with contours, which still looks to me like it shouldn’t work.

Comment: please provide representative input data. I can't design for something you haven't specified sufficiently. this is close to "moving the goalposts". -- yes, as Cris suggests, this erasing operation can potentially be improved if there are many labels. there are lot of options. you absolutely should present actual input data.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to eliminate the common blobs in two images `bitwise_xor` may be helpful.

```
import cv2

set1 =cv2.imread('set1.png')
set2 =cv2.imread('set2.png')

xor_img = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.bitwise_xor(set1,set2))

cv2.imshow('Set 1',set1)
cv2.imshow('Set 2',set2)
cv2.imshow('XOR',xor_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will not work in the case of a partial overlap. Please see an update to my question

Comment: Okey, i misunderstood the problem, so you would like to eliminate any blob even if they partially overlap with blobs from set1. Let me think

Comment: You are correct

Comment: I added another answer but not sure if it satisfies your performance expectation.

Comment: these arrays of cow spots inspired me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of editing the previous answer, I will add another answer.
To eliminate the partially overlapped blobs you should check every blob in `set2`. To do this made a for loop over the contours (corresponindg to blobs) in `set2`, and i this loop i checked if the found blob is intersecting with any other shape in `set1`.
To check the intersection i drew the blobs to a `blank image` and found `bitwise_and` with `set1`. If the resulting image contains any contours then your blob is overlapping with something from `set1`.

Here is the code and results:

```
import cv2
import numpy

#Read set 1 and set 2 images as gray
set1 = cv2.imread('set1.png',0)
set2 = cv2.imread('set2.png',0)
modified_set2 = numpy.zeros((set2.shape[0],set2.shape[1]),numpy.uint8)

contours,hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(set2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #find contours in set 2

#Iterate over contours in set 2
for cnt in contours:
    black = numpy.zeros((set2.shape[0],set2.shape[1]),numpy.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(black,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),-1)

    overlap = cv2.bitwise_and(black,set1) #bitwise and of contour with set1

    #Check if the contour intersects with anything from set1
    cnt_overlap,_ = cv2.findContours(overlap,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
    if len(cnt_overlap) == 0:
        print('No intersection')
        cv2.drawContours(modified_set2,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),-1)


cv2.imshow('Modified Set 2',modified_set2)
cv2.imshow('Set 1',set1)
cv2.imshow('Set 2',set2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is set1:

[image: Set1]

This is set2 blob 1 and blob 2 are partially overlapping with blobs from set1:

[image: Set2]

This is blobs in set2 that are not overlapping at all with blobs from set1:

[image: set2-with-no-overlap]

Comment: How is this different from OP’s code? Drawing the contours and checking intersections is expensive, OP is asking for a faster solution.

Comment: for cnt in contours:
    black = numpy.zeros((set2.shape[0],set2.shape[1]),numpy.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(black,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),-1)

    This is too expensive. Solved it by reusing cv2.getcontours (because it is milliseconds cheap)