# Does OpenCV-python guarantee that a contour remains the same even if other parts of an image change?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, contour, opencv

Concider this situation. you have two images.

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Yes, the upper left figure is the same in both cases. Yes, the other (non-overlapping figures) might be different. Can I be sure that if my figure doesnot overlap with other stuff, then str(cv2.get_contours(...)) yields the same order of points?

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee. it depends on the implementation and what nondeterminism it exhibits in order to be faster (think multithreading). -- the contours may be coming in a different order of course. the list of points making up each contour may *conceivably* be rolled. or not, depends on the implementation. -- I hope you aren't planning to compare shapes by relying on a specific order of points. the only order you can rely on is that they're going around. you can't know what the first point in the list will be.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757314/efficient-algorithm-to-check-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values-in-python-the-v